# Aggregation in Mongodb Java Driver version 3+

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing some problems to get Aggregation to work in Mongodb Java Driver Version 3+

I need to get max, min and average in the same query.

```
db.sensordata.aggregate(
{
$match : {"port":"GOOD_PRODUCT_COUNT", 
          "serial":"MDC-SBO", 
          "collected":{"$gte": new Date("2017-09-12T00:00:00.000Z")}, 
          "x":"y"

}
},
{
"$group": {
        "_id": 0,
        "average": {
            "$avg": "$value"
        },
        "sum": {
             $sum:"$value"
        },  
        "max": {
            "$max": "$value"
        }
        ,  
        "min": {
            "$min": "$value"
        },
        "count": {
                $sum: 1
        }

    }
}
);
```

How can I do it in Java?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
List<Document> results = mongoCollection.aggregate(
   asList(
      match(
            and(
                  eq("port", "GOOD_PRODUCT_COUNT"),
                  eq("serial", "MDC-SBO"),
                  eq("x", "y"),
                  gte("collected", new Date())
              )      
           ),
      group(
           "_id:0",
           avg("average", "$value"),
           sum("sum", "$value"),
           max("max", "$value"),
           min("min", "$value"),
           sum("count", 1)             
      )           
   )            
).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Veeram. I am trying to put a date range but it doesn´t work. Do you have some tip?

Comment: Something like `and(gte("collected", new Date()), lt("collected", new Date()))` ?